# 403 error in Wordpress 4.0 options.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I want to disable comments site-wide on a Wordpress site, but I keep getting this one annoying problem.

I've looked around and all of the results are for older versions of Wordpress. I have a fresh install of Wordpress 4.0 onto a namecheap hosting server.

When I try to disable comments in Settings > Discussion by unchecking the box and clicking on the submit button below, I get redirected to a page that says:

> You don't have permission to access /wp/wp-admin/options.php on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

One suggestion from a few threads from 5-7 years ago was to modify the .htaccess and permissions. I tried, it still is returning the same error. Those suggestions were for older, less secure versions of Wordpress, so I'm thinking there should be a different workaround for 4.0. I also for some reason don't have SSH access to the server, probably because of some stupid namecheap / cpanel restriction.

Comment: It sounds like your file permissions are too strict. What are the permissions of the `/wp-admin` directory (should be 755), and your `wp-options.php` file (should be 644)?

Comment: I have the identical problem on a fresh install Wordpress 4.0 site, also on namecheap.  My wordpress site is installed in the root (not in a wp directory).All extensions are disabled.  I tried adding the following .htaccess file into the wp-admin folder:

    <IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
    </IfModule>

I verified the wp-admin folder has permissions of 755 and the options file has permissions of 644.  Googling reveals quite a few frustrated people with the same problem.

At this point, I wonder if it's namecheap's settings?
No code in comments??

Comment: I'm not using NameCheap for hosting.  It's happening on my site.  The .htaccess fix didn't fix it, and changing permissions didn't fix it.  I edited the files directly where possible.  =(

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and contacted namecheap directly and they corrected it quickly - I don't think there's anything you can do.  Specifically, they said:

> We have whitelisted Mod Security rule which has been triggered. Please try preform necessary actions one more time.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Privileges of wordpress database users.
Check also file & folder permission.
(  a folder permission 755 and file permission 644 )